# get_absolute_url throws a no reverse match

Tags: python, django, reverse, function

why does that not work?

in my models class i have

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return reverse ('core.views.LandingView', args =[str(self.id)])
```

and in my urls i have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', core.views.LandingView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Why does that throw

> NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'visitors.views.LandingView' with
>   arguments '('da697aca-4269-4700-b174-fe6d022ee3a1',)' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

I also tried it with `'index'` instead of `'core.views.LandingView'`.

I checked the docs and also other posts, it's clearly the name but why?

Thanks!

Comment: The regex for your landing view pattern, `r'^$'`, does not include any arguments, but you are providing `self.id` as an argument.

Comment: Also, when using `reverse`, you should use the name `'index'` instead of `'core.views.LandingView`. If you try `reverse('index')` it should work, then you can think about adding the id to the regex.

Comment: url(r'^$', core.views.LandingView.as_view(), name='index') doesn't have any argument. Also you don't need to use 'core.views.LandingView', you suppose to use name which is 'index'. How are you making call to get_absolute_url?